# Loading lots to small size images into auto scrolling list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I am trying to implement trickplay for android TV app. I have list of local file urls to show in auto scrolling RecylerView when user press and hold FF/RW buttons.

I am not using glide for this case because it mostly shows empty images as the scroll speed is so fast

To show images faster I am creating `List<Drawable>`  by creating Drawable

```
 // image cacher
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      cachedImageList.add(Drawable.createFromPath(getPath(i)));
   }




@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
holder.getImageCardView().setImageDrawable(cachedImageList.get(position));

      
    }
```

I am also clearing the Drawable reference as soon as view is recycled

```
 public void onViewRecycled(final MyViewHolder holder) {
        holder.getImageCardView().setImageDrawable(null);
    }
```

I am seeing a memory spike when I load the Drawable into list. Even after calling `cachedImageList.clear()` memory does not return to normal.

What should be the best way to load lots of small Drawable into very fast scrolling RecyclView?

Thanks

Comment: You are setting a null drawable to `ImageView` but the `cachedImageList` still has it so it will not free up the memory. Instead of caching drawables just have an array if resource Ids and use `setImageResource` of even `setDrawable` . its from local so i don't  its will take much time to load the images .

Comment: I am calling cachedImageList.clear() once user done  with seek, however that does not clear the memory